# Control systems to control position of antenna with motor?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering

I want to design a control system with microcontroller to control position or orientation of antenna with BLDC motor with high precision like 0.1 deg and I don't have idea which motor position controller IC I can use or if there is an other idea please share with me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share BLDC motor specifications. This will help point to motor controllers. Also I suggest researching H-Bridge driver circuits.

Comment: A stepper motor may be better.

Comment: There are systems to control antennas already - what do they use?